# How do I specify "Twisted Web" as a pip requirement?

Tags: python, pip, twisted.web, requirements.txt

I am packaging my program and I am having trouble with the "Twisted Web" dependency. I tried inputting all of the following combos in the `setup.py` file:

```
install_requires = ['Twisted Web>=12.2.0'],
install_requires = ['Twisted%20Web>=12.2.0'],
install_requires = ['"Twisted Web">=12.2.0'],
```

but the only thing I get is

```
error in philharmonic setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
```

The rest of the file is OK, because if I set some other single-word package the installation passes without any complaints.

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/307), but I would appreciate any other way of specifying this requirement. Can I input PyPI links or GitHub repo urls in the `install_requires` field? Is there a good resource for the supported syntax, because I didn't find much explanation in the [Hitchhiker's guide](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html)?

Comment: Are you sure you need a comma a at the end of the lines? It makes `install_requires` a tuple.